# Why transform:translatex in this css class does not move the div sideway?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to move a div across a screen. The div is set to `width:100%` initially. But when the transformation starts, the size of the div seems to have shrinked (the blue border just wraps around the text). Why it  is the case?

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Here is my code example

http://codepen.io/kongakong/pen/MKzmMm

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  init();
});

function init() {
  $('input').on('click',
    function () {
      $('.answer-text-2').closest('.answer').addClass('textout');
      $('.answer-hide').addClass('textin');
    });
}
```

**css**

```
.row {
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.answer-text-2 {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: auto;
}

.answer-text-2-new {
  color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 500;
}

.textout {
  /* display: none; */
  margin: -500;
  opacity: 0;
  width: '50%';
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}

.answer-hide {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: '100%';
}
.textin {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(10000px);
  transition: transform 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="contrainer">
  <div>
    <input type='button' value="test"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="answer">
      <span class="answer-text-2">To disappear</span>
    </div>
    <div class="answer-hide">To move sideway

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... Your width of a div called `answer-hide` is set to `auto`, and it's `position` is set to `static` (as for default values). When applying transformation div's `position` is automatically changed to `absolute` (as defined in spec) and `width:auto` for block elements positioned absolutely is something like *shrink to fit*. To fix that, be sure, that your `width` property is properly set, because `width: 100%;` is not equal to `width: '100%';` :)

```
.answer-hide {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, you use

```css
width: '100%';
```

This is not a valid value, because `width` expects a length, not a string. So it's ignored.

Therefore, it has the initial `width: auto`. For [block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) this is the width of the containing block (subtracting margins, paddings and borders).

Then, you use

```css
position: absolute;
```

For [absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width), when `width` and  `right` are `auto`, and `left` is not, the width is given by the [shrink-to-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) algorithm (also called [fit-content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fit-content-measure)).

That's why it shrinks.